# Dynamic logic query builder in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm have 2 table in DB:

```
class Param(models.Model):
    s_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    n_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class ParamValue(models.Model):
    param = models.ForeignKey(Param)
    value = models.IntegerField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
```

I wanted to create dynamic constructor. Is there any library or method for create dynamic logic filter like as Apache Lucene or Solr?
I mean something like this:

```
dyn_filter = parse("(value < 200 AND value__s_name == 'pressure') 
    OR (value > 10 AND value__s_name == 'depth')")
result = ParamValue.objects.filter(dyn_filer)
```

Comment: do you want parse sql or just generate filter dynamic?

Comment: I want generate filter, maybe. Now I'm look at whoosh (http://whoosh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/querylang.html)

Comment: Do you also want a parser or do you only want the ORM to execute the equivalent query?

Comment: I think that I need parser, because query string ("(value < 200 AND ....)") should be stored in database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the library [DjangoQL](https://github.com/ivelum/djangoql). It supports logical operators, comparison operators, parenthesis, table joins, etc.

```
from django.db import models

from djangoql.queryset import DjangoQLQuerySet


class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')

    objects = DjangoQLQuerySet.as_manager()
```

With the example above you can perform search like this:

```
qs = Book.objects.djangoql(
    'name ~ "war" and author.last_name = "Tolstoy"'
)
```

And DjangoQL will execute the equivalent Django queryset.

Comment: It's PERFECT! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Django ORM has the **Q** objects which allows you to write the logic operation **OR** with the Queryset parameters.

The bellow example does exactly what your text (`"(value < 200 AND value__s_name == 'pressure') OR (value > 10 AND value__s_name == 'depth')"`) asks for:

```
from django.db.models import Q
ParamValue.objects.filter(
    Q(value__lt=200, param__s_name='pressure') | Q(value__gt=10, param__s_name='depth')
)
```